# WHY, oh why is there no example code for audio?

Tags: mediaelement.js

There is just code for video?
How about code for audio, especially with flash fallback.
Obviously it is working as there is an example at the top.

But if I just copy the code I only get this:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource test.mp3 failed.
```

This is my .htaccess:

```
AddType audio/aac .aac
AddType audio/mp4 .mp4 .m4a
AddType audio/mpeg .mp1 .mp2 .mp3 .mpg .mpeg
AddType audio/ogg .oga .ogg
AddType audio/wav .wav
AddType audio/webm .webm
```

This is the code for the audio tag, I did include all the stuff as said on the docu:

```
<audio type="audio/mp3" src="test.mp3" preload="none" controls="control"></audio>
```

Comment: What is your question? Why somebody decided not to write an example in some documentation?

Comment: This and how you get it working as on the page of the script.

Comment: Okay basically just how to get it working ;)

Comment: Do you actually want to know why there are no examples? That is the only question in there. If you actually explain what you are trying to do, you might get an answer.... the only reference to what library you probably mean is in the tag. You need context if you want anyone to understand you

Comment: Personally, I don't know why they decided not to write an example for audio. Maybe you could email them.

Comment: I haven't actually tried to use this before, but your mime type from htaccess doesn't match the one in your tag.

Comment: If you go to mediaelementjs.com and click on Support it opens a page where you can ask questions. I thought it is a special stack...don't blame me, I didn't know.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, but it does actually say stackoverflow.com, not stackexchange

Comment: Nevermind, their site does it the same way.

Comment: "I haven't actually tried to use this before, but your mime type from htaccess doesn't match the one in your tag." Can you post this as an answer? Still shows the error, but plays at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested:

I haven't actually tried to use this before, but your mime type from htaccess doesn't match the one in your tag.

There is something else going on here though, since the mediaelementjs.com site appears to do exactly the same.

Glad it works though... sort of.